# Finding the limit of a differentiable, continuous function

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

A function $f : (a, ∞) → \Bbb R$ is differentiable on $(a, ∞)$, and satisfies
$$\lim_{x→∞}(f'(x) + αf(x)) = 0$$
where $α$ is a positive constant

Prove that $\lim_{x→∞}f(x) = 0$.

I think that I should write $f(x)$ as $f(x) = \dfrac{f(x) + \alpha f(x)}{1 +\alpha}$

Is it correct? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you miss a derivative somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165673/limit-of-a-continuous-and-differentiable-function/3165688#3165688

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ahh yes. it should be f'(x) + $\alpha$f(x)

Answer (score 1):

Write $$f(x)=\frac{e^{\alpha x}f(x)}{e^{\alpha x}}$$ By L'Hospital's rule, $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{\alpha x} f'(x)+\alpha f(x)e^{\alpha x}}{\alpha e^{\alpha x }}=\frac{1}{\alpha}\lim_{x \to \infty } [f'(x)+\alpha f(x)]=0$$

Comment: $e^x \to \infty$ faster than any power of $x$, so applying limit we have $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form and hence L'Hospital rule make sense. Am I correct?

Comment: What's wrong? Actually I studied this type of problem in Kenneth Ross book. Here it is! (https://www.math.ust.hk/~mamsxiong/Math1023/Kenneth%20A.%20Ross-ElementaryAnalysis.pdf). See exercise 30.6 in page number 248

Comment: Actually, LH applies if the denominator has infinite limit, what the numerator does is irrelevant.

Comment: then how to get the desired result using the book hint? this exercise appears in Lhospital rule section , and $e^x \to \infty$ ,thats why  I apply it

Comment: Indeed, this is the form (per my previous comment) of LH that's given in your link (pg. 246).

Comment: @DavidMitra: yes! then what's wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong.

Comment: @DavidMitra You are right, but this form of L'Hopital's rule is non-standard. Those who have studied analysis from books like Rudin are not aware of this. When such a theorem is used it is desirable to quote the theorem and give a reference.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, it's not very well known. Most, if not all, of Ross' books state LH in this way. Baby Rudin does as well, actually.